# julia get value of type parameters

Tags: types, julia

I have a parametric type. For example:

```
> Array([1 2;3 4])
```

Its type is

```
> typeof(Array([1 2;3 4]))

Array{Int64,2}
```

I can get the first type parameter using `eltype`:

```
> eltype(typeof(Array([1 2;3 4])))

Int64
```

How can I access second and possibly other type parameters?

Comment: You don't have to write eltype(typeof(Array([1 2;3 4]))), just eltype([1 2; 3 4]) is fine. To construct an array, just use the brackets: [1, 2, 3], no need to wrap it in a constructor. When you write `Array([1 2; 3 4])` you are actually making _two_ arrays: first `[1 2; 3 4]`, and then a _second_ one created by the call to `Array`. So it takes longer and uses twice the amount of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're speaking specifically of `(Abstract)Array` types, then the dimension can be retrieved using [`ndims`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.ndims):

```
julia> ndims(Array{Int64, 2})
2
```

If, on the other hand, you want to write a custom function that extracts a given parameter from a parametric type, you can use build one like this:

```
julia> second_param(::Type{Array{T, N}}) where {T, N} = N
second_param (generic function with 1 method)

julia> second_param(Array{Int64, 2})
2
```

(I'm using `Array` here for the sake of the example, but the same kind of construct could be used to extract parameters from any other parametric type)

Answer (score 3):

What François Févotte recommends is best and safest. However, if you wanted to dig into the internals (again - I would not recommend it in production code, but sometimes it is useful) then you can write:

```
get_parameters(x::DataType) = collect(x.parameters)
```

Now you can get a vector of parameters of `x` for any type that is `DataType`:

```
julia> get_parameters(Vector{Int})
2-element Array{Any,1}:
  Int64
 1

julia> get_parameters(Int)
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> get_parameters(Dict{Int, Union{String, Missing}})
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 Int64
 Union{Missing, String}
```

The benefit here is that `x` you pass can be any `DataType`.